# Angular 2 and single page website

Tags: angular, single-page-application

I'm going to be build a website that has all the content on one page in sections. It will have a navbar fixed at the top and when one of the links is clicked the page will scroll to that section. Pretty standard stuff.

I'm learning Angular 2 and need a site I can build it with commercially. This isn't the type of site I was hoping for to try Angular 2 out on but, at this moment in time, it's the only one I have

Question is, is the Angular 2 framework overkill for a simple site like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Continue learning angular 2, without any second thought.. and once you master it, you will realize its really very easy to implement the simple or any feature in its simplest way you would have imagined using angular 2

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I realise now that it's a bit of a dumb question :D

Comment: Happy coding :)